# Is this solution correct? Show that a set $A$ of open intervals satisfies $|A| \leq \aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a set of open and non-empty intervals (real intervals) such that for all $B,C,D \in A$ we have $B \cap C\cap D= \emptyset$. Show that $|A| \leq \aleph_0$. This is what I did and I would like to know if it is correct. For all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ define $A_q = \{B \in A : q \in B\}$. Obviously $A= \cup_{q \in \Bbb{Q}} A_q$ because every non-empty interval contains a rational number. However, since every three intervals in $A$ do not intersect, we must have $|A_q| <3$ for every rational number $q$. Therefore we represented $A$ as a countable union of countable sets, and therefore $A$ is countable (here by countable I mean at most $\aleph_0$). Is it correct?

Comment: You mistyped "$A\cap B\cap C=\varnothing$" instead of "$B\cap C\cap D=\varnothing$", but other than that all ok. Very good.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @Questioner Oops. I'll edit that. Thank you!